# Can I wrap a widget with another at Runtime

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I was wondering if it's possible to wrap a widget in the widget tree at runtime with another widget?

An example of this would be you a TextField on screen, when I tap on it I wrap a container around it and re-render the widget tree. This is not for in production use and will only be for debug use so no need to worry about the optimisation of the flutter tree.

Any example of this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In that case we can  create 2 separated widgets, you can say we are just duplicating the widget. And in this scenario there will be 2x Widgets. Extra one to handle conditional statement.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh that's not what I want to do. That means if we have 1 million widgets we want to wrap in a new widget we have to create 2 million widgets. We don't have that many, but we'll most likely have in the thousands. over about 50-100 code bases. So that's not an option. I'd like to wrap a widget with another at runtime.

Comment: People think differently, about the question. We can create a separated widget to handle this case that will return the original widget based on condition. In this way, we can minimize the code.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh That makes sense. And it's what we do now. But, if I have 2 thousand widgets I want to wrap based on a specific set of conditions, over 50 code bases I have to go into every code base and, find every widget and write code to make use of a new widget. This would take many developers, many hours, and a lot of money. So I'm trying to innovate on that by figuring out if I can wrap a widget with another at runtime.